# Center two divs in a bootstrap 2.3.2 row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs I'd like to center align in a row side by side. What I have currently centers them but vertically, with one div above the other. What's the correct way to have them in the center of the row left-to-right.

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <div class="span2 center" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
      <p>
        This is div1 ...
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 center" style="border: 1px solid red; float:left;">
      <h4>Header in div 2</h4>
      <div>
        <p>
          This is div 2 ...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  @media (min-width: 1076px) and (min-width: 979px) {
    .row-fluid .span2 {
      margin-left: 5.5%;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .row-fluid .span2 {
      margin-left: 5.5%;
    }
  }

  .center {
    float: none !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
  }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7oucy63/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7oucy63/1/

I would use `display: inline-block` on the elements, and then add a `text-align: center` on the parent container. Keep in mind that `text-align: center` will affect all the children node, so add another `text-align: left` to the element.